# Rerender a QT library GUI component in Golang when new data is inserted in to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, qt, go, apache-age

I have created a desktop application in Golang which I call a function

```
handleSection(layout *widgets.QVBoxLayout)
```

which reads rows from a table in postgresql database, and for each row it creates a new

```
`widgets.NewQGroupBox2`
```

and then add require widget to this Group fox and finally add GroupBox as widget to main layout(passed as argument).

Now, when the database table is updated I want to update this GUI component as well, But I am not able to find how to do this.
Can some one tell me how to do that?

I have tried to return the address of ***widgets.QGroupBox** which contais all the Groupboxes at the end of for loop. and remove it using `layout.removeWidget` function, but it does not works.

Comment: Create a trigger which issues [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) and setup your client app to `Listen` for the notification (channel). You can take the necessary action when the notification is received.

Comment: Does notifying re-renders the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically update a QT library GUI component in Golang when new data is inserted in Postgres then you can use the following method:

- You can use a timer to periodically check the database for updates.
- After the detection of updates, you can update the relevant widgets by refetching the data from the database.